# Is it always possible to extend a homeomorphism from a closed ball in the plane onto a closed disk in a surface to their neighbourhoods?

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology, non-orientable-surfaces

Let $S$ be a two dimensional surface and $D$ a closed disk contained in $S$. Is it true that if $f$ is a homeomorphism from a closed ball $B$ in the plane onto $D$, then $f$ extends to a homeomorphism from a neighbourhood of $B$ in the plane onto a neighbourhood of $D$ in the surface?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you don't mean manifold with boundary (in which case it's not true, since $D$ might already be the whole space!) then yes, it's true.  One way to do it is with the Tubular Neighborhood Theorem by switching to the smooth category.

Let $J$ be the boundary curve of your disc in $S$.  Then it has a tubular neighborhood, which is diffeomorphic to a neighborhood of $J$ in its normal tangent bundle.  For a simple closed curve $J$ that's just an open annulus.  This neighborhood is separated into two components by $J$, one of which will meet the interior of your disc.  Keep the *other* one and glue your annulus homeomorphism and disc homeomorphism together along $J$.

If it's annoying having to go into the smooth category, just be aware that these sorts of theorems get VERY hard without appealing to smooth, algebraic/PL or complex-analytic techniques.

Comment: I agree your argument works in the smooth category, but I don't see why you can move to the smooth category to begin with.  In higher dimensions, you can't in general.  For example, if you embed a ball $B^3$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the interior and boundary of the Alexander Horned sphere, then this embedding of $B^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ does *not* extend to a homeomorphism of a neighborhood of $B^3$.